# How to add inside the json Object in indexed db

Tags: javascript, json, indexeddb

I am new to indexedb db . Is it possible to add more data fields inside the json object in indexeddb I have posted a image what I want to do . I  have timestamp in the keys but in the value side I have a object . Inside Object I have `price:"120",todo:"soap"` now I want to create separate one more index inside this object which will create on some button click.

Image will show how I want to add more value inside json object

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nwvq.png)

this is my add code

```
       function add() {
    //alert($("#todo").val());

    var request = db.transaction(["todostore"], "readwrite")
    .objectStore("todostore")
    .add({ timestamp: "KP" + (new Date()).getTime(), todo: $("#todo").val(),
    price:$("#toprice").val()});

 };
```

also i have created

```
       request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
     alert("baaakshu");
        var request = event.target;
        var tx = request.transaction;
        var store = tx.objectStore("todostore", {keyPath: "timestamp"});
        store.createIndex("bakshu", "lala", { unique: false });

        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Values in the database cannot be modified directly; you need to replace the record's value with a new value. e.g.

```
store.get(key).onsuccess = function(e) {
  var value = e.target.result;
  value.somekey = 'somevalue';
  store.put(value, key);
};
```